# DataTable SearchPanes breaks when executing rebuild()

Tags: javascript, datatable, pane

I am using SearchPanes and it nearly works all perfect - My DataTable fields can dynamically change and therefore I also need to rebuild the SearchPanes data since it can show information which is no longer on the table.

From DataTable SearchPane documentation I am aware that they have 2 functions to achieve this:

1. executing `datatable().searchPanes.rebuild()`
2. executing `datatable().searchPanes.rebuildPane(paneIndex)`

When I execute the 1st option I get the following:

```
jquery.dataTables.min.js:360 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new v (jquery.dataTables.min.js:360)
    at v.iterator (jquery.dataTables.min.js:369)
    at v.<anonymous> (dataTables.searchPanes.min.js:101)
    at Function.rebuild (jquery.dataTables.min.js:377)
    at v.<anonymous> (dataTables.searchPanes.min.js:101)
    at v.iterator (jquery.dataTables.min.js:369)
    at v.<anonymous> (dataTables.searchPanes.min.js:101)
    at Function.rebuild (jquery.dataTables.min.js:377)
    at v.<anonymous> (dataTables.searchPanes.min.js:101)
    at v.iterator (jquery.dataTables.min.js:369)
```

Besides, when I execute the 2nd option I do not get any exception but all the searchPanes get completely blocked and I cannot use them to filter anything at all.

I am currently using SearchPanes version 1.2.1

Should I be doing this in order to achieve what I want to do? What am I making wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think your item 1 `searchPanes.rebuild()` is a valid API call. Did you mean `searchPanes.rebuildPane()`, with no pane index (to rebuild all panes)?

Comment: For item 2 (where you do use a pane index), I cannot recreate your problem. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks for seeing my question! Sorry for not have posted code already - I'm going to re-create the problem on codepen/jsfiddle and I will post it here asap :-)